# My program is saying that i have 0Mb of ram left

Tags: c#, performance

So i wrote program to print in console how much i'm using ram, network, processor, etc. But available ram (in Mb) shows 0 when im using only 30% of my 16gb of ram.

My code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;


namespace Perf_Monitor
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            PerformanceCounter perfCpuCount = new     PerformanceCounter("Processor Information", "% Processor Time", "_Total");
            PerformanceCounter perfMemDowCount = new     PerformanceCounter("Memory", "Available MBytes");
            PerformanceCounter perfNetDowCount = new     PerformanceCounter("Network Adapter", "Bytes Received/sec", "Intel[R] 82579V     Gigabit Network Connection");
            PerformanceCounter perfNetUpCount = new     PerformanceCounter("Network Adapter", "Bytes Sent/sec", "Intel[R] 82579V Gigabit       Network Connection");



            while (true)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                Console.WriteLine("CPU Load:            {0}%",     perfCpuCount.NextValue());
                Console.WriteLine("Available RAM:       {0}",     perfCpuCount.NextValue());
                Console.WriteLine("Network Usage Down:  {0}Mbit/s",     perfNetDowCount.NextValue() / 125000);
                Console.WriteLine("Network Usage Up:    {0}Mbit/s",     perfNetUpCount.NextValue() / 125000);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

This is how it shows up:

[image: My Program]

Comment: Wouldn't you want to print `perfMemDowCount.nextValue()`?

Answer (score 2):

You have a copy/paste error, using `perfCpuCount` twice:

```
Console.WriteLine("CPU Load: {0}%",     perfCpuCount.NextValue());
Console.WriteLine("Available RAM: {0}", perfCpuCount.NextValue());
```

Should be:

```
Console.WriteLine("CPU Load: {0}%",     perfCpuCount.NextValue());
Console.WriteLine("Available RAM: {0}", perfMemDowCount.NextValue());
```

Comment: Nailed it.  And the reason it prints as 0, and not something that looks like a CPU load, could be because of the two calls to the counter in rapid succession.